# ROR how to use YML aliases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, aliases

For example:
**In "EN.yml":**

```
en:
  aliases:
    - &test test_passed
  some: ["bla-bla", *test, "bla-bla-bla,", *test]
```

---

**In view.html.erb:**

```
<% @array = t('some') %>
<%= @array.join(" ") %>
```

---

**RESULT in Browser:**

```
bla-bla test_passed bla-bla-bla, test_passed
```

---

My Question: Maybe there is simple way to do this without crutches?

Comment: This looks simple enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in variables to the translation.

In en.YML

```
en:
  aliases:
    - &test test_passed
  some: "bla-bla %{test} bla-bla-bla %{test2}"
```

In view

```
<%= t('some', :test => test_value, :test2 => test2_value) %>
```